# Read perticular characters from a word using shell script in linux

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a variable values stored in environment variables.
when I do

```
echo $myvar
```

I can see the value. Below is the example

```
~% echo $myvar
abcdefghijkl73
```

Now, I would like to read 8th/13th/14th character from this variable value and print the value

```
h73
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks you so much @begemotv2718.
Exactly what I was looking for. life savior !!!
using echo $myvar | cut -c 8,13,14 for my scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use BASH:

```
myvar="abcdefghijkl73"; echo ${myvar:7:1}${myvar:12:1}${myvar:13:1}
```

See "Parameter expansion" section in **man bash**
For the general POSIX shell you need to use external utility to do this:

```
echo $myvar | cut -c 8,13,14
```

This uses **cut** utility (more information about this utility you can find in **info coreutils**